# Using Eigen and C++ to do a colsum of massive matrix product

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I am trying to compute colsum(N * P), where N is a sparse, 1M by 2500 matrix, and P is a dense 2500 by 1.5M matrix.  I am using the Eigen C++ library with Intel's MKL library.  The issue is that the matrix N*P can't actually exist in memory, it's way too big (~10 TB).  My question is whether Eigen will be able to handle this computation through some combination of lazy evaluation and parallelism?  It says here that Eigen won't make temporary matrices unnecessarily: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicLazyEvaluation.html

But does Eigen know to compute N * P in piecewise chunks that will actually fit in memory?  IE: it will have to do something like colsum(N * P_1) ++ colsum(N * P_2) ++ .. ++ colsum(N * P_n), where P is split into n different submatrices column-wise and "++" is concatenation.

I am working with 128 GB RAM.

Answer (score 1):

I gave it a try but ended up with a bad malloc (I'm only running on 8GB on Win8). I set up my `main()` and used a not inline `colsum` function I wrote.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd dense = Eigen::MatrixXd::Random(1000, 100000);
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> sparse(100000, 1000);
    typedef Triplet<int> Trip;
    std::vector<Trip> trps(dense.rows());
    for(int i = 0; i < dense.rows(); i++)
    {
        trps[i] = Trip(20*i, i, 2);
    }
    sparse.setFromTriplets(trps.begin(), trps.end());

    VectorXd res = colsum(sparse, dense);
    std::cout << res;
    std::cin >> argc;
    return 0;
}
```

The attempt was simply:

```
__declspec(noinline) VectorXd 
colsum(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &sparse, const Eigen::MatrixXd &dense)
{
    return (sparse * dense).colwise().sum();
}
```

That had a bad malloc. Sol it looks like you have to split it up manually on your own (unless someone else has a better solution).

### EDIT

I improved the function a bit, but the get the same bad malloc:

```
__declspec(noinline) VectorXd 
colsum(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &sparse, const Eigen::MatrixXd &dense)
{
    return (sparse * dense).topRows(4).colwise().sum();
}
```

### EDIT 2

Another option would be to make the sparse matrix dense and force a lazy evaluation. I don't think that it would work with a sparse matrix (oh well).

```
__declspec(noinline) VectorXd 
colsum(const Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> &sparse, const Eigen::MatrixXd &dense)
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd denseSparse(sparse);
    return denseSparse.lazyProduct(dense).colwise().sum();
}
```

This doesn't give me the bad malloc, but computes a lot of pointless `0*x_i` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Especially, when products are involved, Eigen often evaluates parts of expressions into temporaries. In some situations this could be optimized but is not implemented yet, in some cases this is essentially the most efficient way to implement it.

However, in your case you could simply calculate the colsum of `N` (a 1 x 2500 vector) and multiply that by `P`.
*Maybe* future versions of Eigen will be able to make this kind of optimization themselves, but most of the time it is a good idea to make problem-specific optimizations oneself before letting the computer do the rest of the work.

Btw: I'm afraid `sparse.colwise()` is not implemented yet, so you must compute that manually. If you are lazy, you can instead compute `Eigen::RowVectorXd Nsum = Eigen::RowVectorXd::Ones(N.rows())*P;` (I have not checked it, but this might actually get optimized to near optimal code, with the most recent versions of Eigen).